# useMatch for multilpe patterns to test on in react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I have the following array:

```js
const tabsList = [
  { 
    pathPattern: 'users/'
    label: 'Manage users'
  },
  {
    pathPattern: 'users/:id',
    label: 'Edit user profile'
  }
]
```

I need a method from `react-router-dom` to tell me which of the above array entries matches the current pathname.

Based on that, I will be able to color the active list item in my component styles.

I found the method `useMatch()` which looks like does almost what I want, however, it does not accept an array, it only accepts one string pattern to use for comparison.

```js
// example: current path is /users/82374023854321
const isAllUsersMatch = useMatch('/users') // null
const isUserIdMatch = useMatch('/users/:id') // { ...PathMatch<string> }
```

it works, but it's not good, I have to create a separate variable like that for every item in the array.

Is there something like the following in `react-router-dom`?

```js
const tabsList = [
  { 
    pathPattern: 'users/'
    label: 'Manage users'
  },
  {
    pathPattern: 'users/:id',
    label: 'Edit user profile'
  }
] 
const activeListItem = tabsList.some((listItem)=> doesItMatch(listItem.pathPattern))
```

I would have done this with the hook, but in react you can't use a hook inside a callback, so the following would not work:

```js
// const activeListItem = tabsList.some((listItem)=> doesItMatch(listItem.pathPattern))
const activeListItem = tabsList.some((listItem)=> useMatch(listItem.pathPattern)) // ERROR
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track iterating over the `tabsList` array. If all you need is to match the current path to one in a configuration object/array, then instead of using the `useMatch` hook, which doesn't work in a nested callback function, you can use the [`matchPath`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/utils/match-path) utility function that the `useMatch` hook uses directly.

```js
import { matchPath, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const tabsList = [
  {
    pathPattern: "users/",
    label: "Manage users"
  },
  {
    pathPattern: "users/:id",
    label: "Edit user profile"
  }
];

...

const { pathname } = useLocation();
const activeListItem = tabsList.find(({ pathPattern }) =>
  matchPath(pathPattern, pathname)
);
```

And the above abstracted into a custom hook:

```js
const useTabsListMatches = (tabsList = []) => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  return tabsList.find(({ pathPattern }) =>
    matchPath(pathPattern, pathname)
  );
}
```

```js
const activeListItem = useTabsListMatches(tabsList);
```

[image: Edit usematch-for-multilpe-patterns-to-test-on-in-react-router-dom]

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use `react-router`'s [`matchRoutes()`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/utils/match-routes) if you change the shape of your object:

```
const location = useLocation()

const matches = matchRoutes([{ 
  path: 'users/',
  label: 'Manage users',
}, {
  path: 'users/:id',
  label: 'Edit user profile',
}], location)
```

Comment: what are the `path` and `label` props here?

Comment: It's the same object you had in your question. You'll get all the ones that match.

Comment: I am getting "Type '{ label: string; value: string; }' is not assignable to type 'AgnosticRouteObject'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'label' does not exist in type 'AgnosticRouteObject'"

Comment: I'm also using a custom interface for routes in one of my projects and I'm not getting that error. You should probably check your TS config. Alternatively, just map or update that object to only contain the paths.